# Python: replace values of a categorical variable to something else in a data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, encoding, categorical-data

i have a pandas data frame in which there's a column named label of categorical type having three categories as **('>5' , '<30' , 'NO')**. I want to change **('>5' , '<30')** these two categories to **'yes'** and i can't seem to figure out how.
I want to do this with python and also with dtale (python package).

I have managed to do it in python this way:

```
label_changed = {"label": {">5": "YES", "<30": "YES"}}
bp = bp.replace(label_changed)
```

Is there any other, more efficient, way to do this?

Also I still haven't managed to do this using dtale.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `replace()` and pass a list with the values to be replaced and then the parameter with replacement, it's a bit tidier when you want to replace multiple values with a unique one:

```
to_replace = [">5","<30"]
bp = bp.replace(to_replace,"Yes")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also perform this in D-Tale using the "Replacements" function.  You can get to this feature by clicking on the name of your column in the main data grid and then clicking "Replacements".

From there, you can either edit your column inplace or create a new column (so you don't lose your original data).  Then follow these steps:

- Choose "Value(s)" (which is the default)
- Enter `>5` in "Search For"
- Keep "Raw" selected and enter `Yes` in the text input box
- Click the "+" button
- Enter `<30` in "Search For"
- Keep "Raw" selected and enter `Yes` in the text input box
- Click the "+" button
- Click "Replace"

Should show you the code that went into building the new column or updated column if you click the "Code Export" button from the main menu as well.